# Geometrical Application of Calculus with Speed

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Two vehicles are heading for a crossroad (point $C$) and intend to pass straight through.

Vehicle $A$ is $100\,\mathrm{km}$ due North travelling at $80\,\mathrm{km}/\mathrm{hr}$ towards $C$
Vehicle $B$ is $150\,\mathrm{km}$ due East travelling at $90\,\mathrm{km}/\mathrm{hr}$ towards $C$

Show that after time $t$, the distance $D$ between them is given by:

$$D^2=100(145t^2-430t+325)$$

Comment: Pythagoras seems helpful here.

Comment: I figured it out! But now I need to determine the time that it takes to minimise the distance between them. I'm assuming that I need to make y'=0, but I can't find y'!

Answer (score 1):

Since the square function is strictly increasing on the non-negative reals, we might take $(D^2)'$ instead of $D'$, which is $100(290t-430)$.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Hoppe mentioned, Pythagorean theorem will yield the desired function in D.

If you connect the top of the North part to the right side of the east part to create a triangle, we have, (t = time in hours):

$(100km - 80\frac{km}{hr}t)^2 + (150km - 90\frac{km}{hr}t)^2 = D^2$

Now just simplify.

Comment: Thank you so so much! Do you know how to determine the time that it will take to minimise the distance between them?